# How can I create a new column in df with min value between selected columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
data = {
        'A':[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        'B':[0,0,1,1,0,1,4,1,2],
        'C':[0,10,130,1,0,1,4,1,12]
       }

X=5

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df["D"]=min(df["A"],X)
print(df)
```

I've tried to create a new column - D, with the minimum value from A and X for each row but I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: I've changed the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the pandas method [`Series.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
df['D'] = df['A'].clip(upper=X)
```

python `min` does not work as it expects a single argument, it cannot compare two Series of data points

Comment: I've edited the answer since OP changed his question which invalidated the then correct answer. Please feel free to roll back/ edit the changes if not ok.